# journeyapp's barcodeview showing black view only

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have setup a barcode scanner using [JourneyApp's BarCode Scanner Library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

I have added dependencies just like in the read-me of the library.

Then, I set up a BarCode View in my main activity like this

main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/barcode_scanner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I leave the MainActivity.java as default. This is it's OnCreate Method

```
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
```

I have added Camera Permission in my manifest too.

When I run the app on the phone. The BarCodeView shows only a black screen. Am I doing anything wrong here?

[image: Black Screen]

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the sample code inside journeyapp's repository [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java).

You have to `resume` and `pause` the barcode view inside `onResume()` and `onPause()` respectively.

So, inside `onCreate()` message you have to get a handler for the `BarcodeView` view:

```
BarcodeView barcodeView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.continuous_scan); 
   barcodeView = (DecoratedBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner);               
}
```

And also you have to add both `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    barcodeView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    barcodeView.pause();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been 6 six months since the question was asked but maybe someone else will go through this problem. (I do really hope you found the solution).

Your layout is completely correct, you're just missing the initialisation code for the barcodeView.

In your activity's onResume method add :

```
protected void onResume () {
    BarcodeView v = (BarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.barcode_view);
    v.resume();
    v.decodeSingle(new BarcodeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
            // Do whatever you want with the result
        }

        @Override
        public void possibleResultPionts(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this can help !

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the following permission in AndroidManifesl.xml

From version 6 of Android you need to request permission at runtime. Follows documentation to request permission at runtime.
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en

Comment: worked after adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` permissions in the AndroidManifesl.xml

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. But in my case, I got the following from the logs

> W/TextureView: A TextureView or a subclass can only be used with
>   hardware acceleration enabled.

So I just set the hardware acceleration for the activity in the manifest file. and It worked.!

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```